# EPiServer.Core.TypeMismatchException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, episerver

I am new to EPIServer, asp.net and C# development and trying to understand the following issue.

I ran an instance of EPIServer CMS from Visual Studio. I opened up a pre-existing test page and added a Video Player block (containing a youtube link) to the Main Content Area. Then I published my page and had a look at it in the frontend.

I then go back in to edit the page, I click on the Video Player block and select Edit, then I am taken to the page where I can edit the settings of this video player block, but Visual Studio stops, and I get an EPiServer.Core.TypeMismatchException error in Visual Studio.

Error message:

> Exception thrown: 'EPiServer.Core.TypeMismatchException' in
>   EPiServer.dll An exception of type
>   'EPiServer.Core.TypeMismatchException' occurred in EPiServer.dll but
>   was not handled in user code Content with id '9913_22802' is of type
>   'Castle.Proxies.VideoPlayerBlockProxy' which does not inherit required
>   type 'Example.Site.Models.Pages.SitePageData'

The following code line is being marked in Visual Studio as being the source of the problem:

```
var currentPage = _contentLoader.Get<SitePageData>(currentContentLink);
```

Here is some context:

```
public virtual LayoutModel CreateLayoutModel(ContentReference currentContentLink, RequestContext requestContext)
{
    var startPageContentLink = SiteDefinition.Current.StartPage;

    // Use the content link with version information when editing the startpage,
    // otherwise the published version will be used when rendering the props below.
    if (currentContentLink.CompareToIgnoreWorkID(startPageContentLink))
    {
        startPageContentLink = currentContentLink;
    }

    var startPage = _contentLoader.Get<StartPage>(startPageContentLink);
    var currentPage = _contentLoader.Get<SitePageData>(currentContentLink);

    var model = new LayoutModel
    {
        Logotype = startPage.SiteLogotype,
        AlternativeLogotype = currentPage.AlternativeLogo.GetContent() as SiteLogotypeBlock,
        GoogleTagManager = startPage.GoogleTagManager,
        LogotypeLinkUrl = new MvcHtmlString(_urlResolver.GetUrl(SiteDefinition.Current.StartPage)),
        AdditionalNavigationItems = startPage.AdditionalNavigationItems ?? new EPiServer.SpecializedProperties.LinkItemCollection(),
        Footer = startPage.FooterBlock,
        LoggedIn = requestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated,
        MarketPlaceUrl = startPage.MarketPlaceLink.GetContent() as GeneralLinkBlock,
        LoginUrl = new MvcHtmlString(UrlResolver.Current.GetUrl(startPage.LoginPageLink)),
        SearchActionUrl = new MvcHtmlString(UrlResolver.Current.GetUrl(startPage.SearchPageLink)),
        IsInReadonlyMode = _databaseMode.DatabaseMode == DatabaseMode.ReadOnly
    };

    SetCountriesAndLanguages(GetLanguageVersions(currentContentLink, startPage), model);

    var cookie = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[Global.CookieNames.CookiesDisclaimerViewed];

    if (cookie == null || cookie.Value.Equals(bool.FalseString))
    {
        SetCookieDisclaimer(model, startPage);

        requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(
            new HttpCookie(Global.CookieNames.CookiesDisclaimerViewed, bool.TrueString)
            {
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)
            });
    }

    return model;
}
```

The applicable controller:

```
namespace Example.Site.Controllers
{
    public class VideoPlayerBlockController : BlockController<VideoPlayerBlock>
    {
        public override ActionResult Index(VideoPlayerBlock currentContent)
        {            
            return PartialView(new VideoPlayerViewModel(currentContent));
        }
    }
}
```

The view:

```
@model VideoPlayerViewModel

<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item"
                        src=@Model.VideoURL
                        frameborder="0"
                        allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"
                        @Model.AllowFullScreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

VideoPlayerViewModel.cs:

```
using Example.Site.Models.Blocks;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;

namespace Example.Site.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class VideoPlayerViewModel
    {
        private const string YouTubeLink = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/";

        private const string YouTubeNoCookieLink = "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/";

        private const string StartAtParameter = "start=";

        private const string ShowVideoSuggestionsParameter = "rel=0";

        private const string PlayerControlsParameter = "controls=0";

        private const string TitleAndPlayerActionsParameter = "showinfo=0";

        private const string AllowFullscreenParameter = "allowfullscreen";

        private const string DontAllowFullscreenParameter = "donotallowfullscreen";

        //private const string VideoWidth = "width=";

        //private const string VideoHeight = "height=";

        public string VideoURL { get; set; }

        public string AllowFullScreen { get; set; }

        public VideoPlayerViewModel(VideoPlayerBlock videoBlock)
        {
            AllowFullScreen = videoBlock.AllowFullScreenMode ? AllowFullscreenParameter : DontAllowFullscreenParameter;

            Uri uri = new UriBuilder(videoBlock.YouTubeLink).Uri;
            var queryDictionary = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
            var filmCode = queryDictionary.HasKeys() ? queryDictionary["v"] : uri.Segments[1];
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(videoBlock.EnablePrivacyEnhancedMode ? YouTubeNoCookieLink : YouTubeLink).Append(filmCode);

            var parameters = new List<string>();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(videoBlock.StartAt) && !Regex.IsMatch(videoBlock.StartAt, "^[0]?[0][:][0]{2}$"))
            {
                var timeString = videoBlock.StartAt.Split(':');
                if (Int32.TryParse(timeString[0], out var minutes) && (Int32.TryParse(timeString[1], out var seconds)))
                {
                    parameters.Add(StartAtParameter + (minutes * 60 + seconds).ToString());
                }
            }

            //if (videoBlock.CustomVideoWidth > 1 && videoBlock.CustomVideoWidth < 100)
            //{
            //    parameters.Add(VideoWidth + videoBlock.CustomVideoWidth);
            //}

            if (!videoBlock.ShowVideosSuggestions)
            {
                parameters.Add(ShowVideoSuggestionsParameter);
            }

            if (!videoBlock.ShowPlayerControls)
            {
                parameters.Add(PlayerControlsParameter);
            }

            if (!videoBlock.ShowTitleAndPlayerActions)
            {
                parameters.Add(TitleAndPlayerActionsParameter);
            }

            if (parameters.Any())
            {
                builder.Append("?" + parameters[0]);
            }

            foreach (var parameter in parameters.Skip(1))
            {
                builder.Append("&" + parameter);
            }

            VideoURL = builder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

What is the issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason your `BlockData` content is being rendered by a view that requires the model to be of type `SitePageData`. In other words, it seems you're rendering a block with a page view.

But since it's failing in edit mode, you're perhaps just lacking a preview renderer for your block type, i.e. the view that controls how the block is rendered by itself in on-page edit mode.

Does block previewing work for other block types?

Details on block preview in edit mode: https://world.episerver.com/documentation/developer-guides/CMS/rendering/preview-rendering-for-blocks/

Comment: I found a controller and it does in fact contain "return PartialView()". I have added it above to the original question.

Comment: What does the block view look like? Do you have something like `VideoPlayerBlock.cshtml` somewhere?

Comment: Yes, found it in the Views folder. Added to original question above.

Comment: You should probably add `VideoPlayerViewModel.cs` as well.

Comment: Done, sorry new to this all.

Comment: Edited answer, but TL;DR: ensure you have a preview renderer for your block type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181282/discussion-between-ted-nyberg-and-partisanentity).